# Change default gateway on windows hosted network

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, netsh

I used the following command to create a hosted network.

`netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=[ssid]  key=[keyphrase]`

I would like to change the default gateway and given IP ranges from `192.168.137.1` to say `192.168.10.1`. I tried everyting but couldn't get it to work. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't configurable in the network settings in Windows and has to be changed in the registry editor. In the run prompt enter regedit. Next navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\services\SharedAccess\Parameters`.
Change just `StandaloneDhcpAddress` if your only using Wireless Hosted Network but if you are sharing internet to it with ICS then also set `ScopeAddress` to `192.168.10.1`.

You will probably have to run `netsh wlan stop hostednetwork` and then `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` for the change to take affect. If you are sharing internet to the wireless then you might need to re-share in the windows network settings as well for the changes to take affect. Depending on your setup you might have issues with IP conflicts if you have anther device giving out IP address on `192.168.10.xxx`

See this [superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/564111/96525) for reference.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.