# Windows 10 adhoc connection and DHCP control

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, wireless-access-point

I have set up my hostednetwork and it's all working really well with static IP addresses. I have my main laptop (running windows 10) running and FTP server via IIS and I have attached devices uploading files. I am not sharing any internet connection, this is purely a closed network between my laptop and devices that need to FTP files to it.

I want to add a device that does not support static IP addresses, so I'm starting a little bit again as the hostednetwork stuff is defaulted to DHCP.

I am starting the hosted network the usual way:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=MYSSID key=12345678
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

My assumption is that now it's running all the gear it needs for at least DHCP to be running, however looking at the local IP address, it seems to be a microsoft private one, for example, my windows 10 laptop is currently set to "`169.254.181.225 (Preferred)`" according to ipconfig.

I found [this resource](https://superuser.com/questions/633772/change-default-gateway-on-windows-hosted-network) and [this resource](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/Windows7/AdminTips/Network/ChangeIPAddressofWirelessHostedNetwork.html) that say the default for the host (my laptop) should be `192.168.137.1` and the I can control the DCHP range by registry fiddling. Looking on my laptop it's set to this default `192.168.137.1` but this address is not connectable from anything, so it appears to not be the host of the windows 10 laptop that's configuring everything.

While looking at DHCP, it seems that the `ipconfig /renew` just hangs.

What I am concluding from this is that the windows 10 laptop does not do DHCP at all. Nothing really jumps out at me in the "turn windows featured on" list.

I also thought that since the laptop is controlling the DHCP and network connection, that maybe simple DNS might work so I connected another windows device (it got a 169.254 address also - no DHCP??) and I tried to `telnet scanbook 21` (where scanbook is the name of the laptop), and it won't work.

So, my question is, how do I set up my windows 10 laptop to issue DHCP addresses to connecting clients while still maintaining it's own address in some connectable way?

Comment: `while still maintaining it's own address in some connectable way` - so you need to be connected to two networks at once - one local over wifi and one wired internet - is that right?

Comment: No, I want to be in the middle of a field with my laptop running win10. Another device connects to the hosted network and can then (without any fiddling) attach to the FTP server and upload to it. But, if the laptop is attached to my home network it still needs to be able to connect to that and be used as a regular laptop. So, I'm after some way of controlling DHCP on the hosted network only. For example, set the laptop to have a static IP of, say 192.168.1.1, and run a DHCP server to hand out 192.168.1.2-100, but then whats the `192.168.137.1` all about? isn't that supposed to be working?

Comment: Check this answer: http://superuser.com/a/940050/285900

Comment: Thanks Vojtěch, that's where I kinda thought I ended up, Do I delete this question since it's answered elsewhere? If you add it as an answer with a summary, I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Network devices getting an IP address in the 169.254.x.x range?](https://superuser.com/questions/1106931/network-devices-getting-an-ip-address-in-the-169-254-x-x-range)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a WiFi hotspot in Windows 10 is aimed more on internet connection sharing, so the DHCP server is not really configurable.

One possible way to create your own wifi network using Win 10 is to assign a static IP address to the laptop's virtual wifi adapter and to configure some third party DHCP server.

This is described [in detail already in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/940050/285900).

Comment: this one isn't clear clear: ` to assign a static IP address to the laptop's **the** virtual wifi adapter` (should you remove the "the"?)

Comment: @JinSnow Little more reputation score and you would be able to edit it yourself. Thanks.