One-to-one NAT on Windows 10
I have three computers:

Host A: Linux PC, with IP 192.168.1.50/24
Host B: Windows VM running on Host A, with IP 192.168.1.100/24 (host-only network) and 192.168.2.100 (vpn)
Host C: PC with any OS (typically Linux or Windows) with IP 192.168.2.150/24 (vpn)

The network diagram is as follows:
  HOST A (192.168.1.50/24) <---> (192.168.1.100) HOST B (192.168.2.100) <--->  (192.168.2.150) HOST C

    

Host A is configured with the following static route: route add 192.168.3.0/24 via 192.168.1.100 and Host B has IP packet forwarding enabled.
I want to achieve the following:

Host A connects to 192.168.3.150, the packets are sent to Host B
Host B translates 192.168.3.150 -> 192.168.2.150 and forwards the packets to Host C
Host C receives the packages and eventually replies with the reversed route

If Host B was a Linux machine I would obtain this with iptables or nftables quite easily, but I have been looking for the same thing on Windows and came up empty handed.
The only semi-relevant elements I found are:

netsh interface portproxy but it only provides port forwarding, while I want to obtain full forwarding
Internet Connection Sharing, but it does not offer configurable NAT (I cannot have Host A connect to 192.168.2.150, let's say because Host A has another interface configured with 192.168.3.0/24 on a different network than Host C)
Powershell New-NetNat, but either it does not accomplish what I seek or I failed to understand it

Thank you in advance to anyone able to help!

I could not find any way to implement NAT as I inteded, however I managed to solve my specific problem, which was to conenct Host A and C directly: I am sharing this hoping others might find it useful in other cases.
I used ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) on host B to share the 192.168.2.0/24 connection with the 192.168.1.0/24 adapter (thanks to this awesomely detailed guide).
Then I "solved" the subnet conflict by setting a temporary route on Host A with higher specificity (ip route add 192.168.2.150/32 via 192.168.1.100) only while the vpn connection is active.
This route is added via a script that is manually run on Host A by the user when the vpn connection is established, then the script sleeps and when the user is done using the vpn they can terminate it and the temporary route gets removed.
This is more of a bypass than a solution, but it is acceptable in my case.

You can specify the ICS dhcp pool with a registry setting: https://superuser.com/a/564111/673426
If you don't need NAT, you can enable full forwarding on the interface properties (uses RRAS): https://serverfault.com/questions/929081/how-can-i-enable-packet-forwarding-on-windows
New-NetNat is generally for hyper-v guest networks
If Host B is running the VPN server service, then it may be easiest to configure NAT there, depending on the vpn you're using.

Thank you, unfortunately Nat is a requirement since host A is connected to another network with the same subnet as Host C (192.168.2.0), which disqualifies ICS. Furtgermore the NAT i need is one-to-one NAT (Basic), not One-To-Many.

@Bonvi which devices do you have control of? If the issue is duplicate subnets, then that should just be fixed. I think the only other option you have with Win10 is bridging adapters, which is not always possible with a vpn. The server versions of Windows have routing and nat tools, but not 10/11 https://openvpn.net/cloud-docs/owner/networks-and-gateways/networks/enabling-routing-and-nat-on-microsoft-windows-server-2016.html

In my case I have full control of both A and B devices and partial control over the test of the network, but changing subnet is not a option due to external network constraints. Anyway, even if I could not find a way to implement one-to-one NAT I did find a solution to my problem. Thank you for helping!
